# Dynamic change of dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have and issue that i can't wrap my head around, so i hope i could get some help and new knowlage to use.

i am building a form, where the user needs to book an item, but once selected i will not have it been able to be selected again.

so what my plan was, is to have a dropdown menu , that you can select what ever from, if you want one item more , you click a button and get a new dropdown menu, allowing you to select a new item, but this new dropdown, should not contain the item from the first dropdown.

i had tried to build a thing like this

```
$(function() {
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        dropdownvalue = $(this).val();
        $('.dropdown').not(this).find('option[value="' + dropdownvalue + '"]').remove();
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/loonitun/tya85x4j/2/

How ever, if my user changes mind, the option is now gone, even if something else is selected ( i know it is the Remove part in the javascript, but i am unsure how to restore the previous option )

if anyone have an solution, or some guidence to how i can get it done i would apreciate it very much.

an alternative solution i had in my mind, that may work, was to do an onchange add to array, but then i would need another dropdown to remove items from that array, and i think that may confuse the user.

Comment: One easy way would be to set the options to `display:none` instead of removing them. (But I don’t think Internet Explorer plays along with that, it still shows them; but if you `disabled` them as well, users could not select them any more.) With any solution that actually removes options, you would also have to figure out the right position to re-insert them again, so that’s going to be more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is - filter your options when you select someting instead of removing them from the array.

for example

`let options = [1, 2, 3, 4] // this is an array of options with ids
let valuesSelected = []; // once you choose a value from the dropdown you need to push it to valuesSelectedArray`

Every time you choose something in a dropdown you need to filter this value out of you **options** array

```
options.filter(option => !valuesSelected.includes(option))
```

this will give you array of options without values you already selected.

Comment: This may be the best solution for my issue, as i can restore the dropdown if user changes mind.